# mergetool from .gitconfig being ignored?

Tags: git, beyondcompare, git-config

`git config --global mergetool.bc3 "\"c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\""`

`git mergetool`

`/usr/lib/git-core/git-mergetool--lib: line 116: bcompare: command not found`

This is extremely odd, because both `./.git/config` and `~/.gitconfig` look correct. Neither lists an entry for `bcompare`. Can git read or store configuration from anywhere other than `.git/config` or `~/.gitconfig`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like the same issue as [this guy](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.msysgit/13188) had.  It appears bc3 is a builtin tool name, and git won't allow that name to be overridden.  Try using a name other than bc3.

I used "BeyondCompare3"

```
[mergetool "BeyondCompare3"]
    path = C:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 3/bcomp.exe
    cmd = \"C:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 3/bcomp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\"
```

Comment: That exactly explains what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to override the path for a merge tool, you just need to set the variable `mergetool.<tool>.path`.

Custom merge tools can be specified with `mergetool.<tool>.cmd` (which shouldn't be necessary for Beyond Compare 3) but a variable of the form `mergetool.<tool>` has no meaning for `git mergetool`. If you were directed to try this from the documentation perhaps you can say where so this can be fixed.

Comment: It's necessary if you're running out of cygwin.